# Html table tr inside td

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to create a table in HTML. I have the following design to create. I had added a `<tr>` inside the `<td>` but somehow the table is not created as per the design.

[image]

Can anyone suggest me how I can achieve this?

**I am unable to create Name1 | Price1 sections.**

Answer (score 215, accepted):

You must add a full table inside the td

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                ...
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add full table inside a td?? I never did that, that's why i am asking this. If it is than its really great

Comment: you can put almost everything into a td, only html, body and head are not allowed I think

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i was scared of. I looked up on google hoping that there was another way out

Comment: Well as of now, it doesn't throw any error when I put tr s in td, infact I've put many tr s inside some td s because my app renders arrays of objects within some properties, and it works across all browsers, (don't know about IE, as I did not test it in IE), anyone interested can check it out - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7aman , Note: it is an Angular app, not sure that Angular is behind this behavior.

Comment: Even though it does not throw an error in your browser it is false, and may throw errors in other browsers or circumstances You should always try to use HTML-Elements in their intended use, like not using block-Elements inside of inline-Elements

Answer (score 51):

You cannot put tr inside td. You can see the allowed content from [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) documentation about `td`. The relevant information is in the *permitted content* section.

Another way to achieve this is by using `colspan` and `rowspan`. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/80s4fb7L/).

HTML:

```
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td>Name 1</td>
  <td>Name 2</td>
  <td colspan="2">Name 3</td>
  <td>Name 4</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td rowspan="3">ITEM 1</td>
  <td rowspan="3">ITEM 2</td>
  <td>name1</td>
  <td>price1</td>
  <td rowspan="3">ITEM 4</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>name2</td>
  <td>price2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>name3</td>
  <td>price3/td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And some CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse       
}

td {
   border: 1px solid #000000
}
```

Comment: putting table inside table is totally valid, write a simple html code where you insert a table inside the TD and paste it in the w3 validator: http://validator.w3.org/check  You will notice it will passed. all errors are related to the doctype and head missing tags.

Comment: putting a table element inside tr in invalid while putting a table inside a td is valid..you can validate on https://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: I think the intended meaning here was that a table inside of a table is an odd approach for the scenario, as `colspan` & `rowspan` are intended for solving this problem.

Comment: Not sure why this solution gets so many upvotes. The posted code is utterly opaque without a browser, achieving a visual goal at the expense of the logical relationship that a table is supposed to represent. And, as noted by @Malloc, its first sentence is patently false.

Answer (score 24):

You can solve without nesting tables.

```html
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ABC</th>
            <th>ABC</th>
            <th colspan="2">ABC</th>
            <th>ABC</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">Item1</td>
            <td rowspan="4">Item1</td>
            <td colspan="2">Item1</td>
            <td rowspan="4">Item1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name1</td>
            <td>Price1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name2</td>
            <td>Price2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name3</td>
            <td>Price3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item2</td>
            <td>Item2</td>
            <td colspan="2">Item2</td>
            <td>Item2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 9):

Full Example:

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>
      <table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
          <td>Name 1</td>
          <td>Price 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name 2</td>
          <td>Price 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name 3</td>
          <td>Price 3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>Item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice! Very nice.

Answer (score 8):

Try this code

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td colspan="2">Name 3</td>
    <td>Name 4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">ITEM 1</td>
    <td rowspan="3">ITEM 2</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>price</td>
    <td rowspan="3">ITEM 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>price</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add a new `table` in the `td` you want. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AbE3Q/

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item1</td>
    <td>Item2</td>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>qweqwewe</td>
          <td>qweqwewe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>qweqwewe</td>
          <td>qweqwewe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>qweqwewe</td>
          <td>qweqwewe</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>Item3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

Put another table inside the td element like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gzTCL/).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>name1</td>
                    <td>price1</td>
                </tr>
...
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>ABC</td>
    </tr>
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check this just use table inside table like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>ABC</th>
      <th>ABC</th>
      <th>ABC</th>
      <th>ABC</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item1</td>
      <td>Item1</td>
      <td>
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td>name1</td>
            <td>price1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name2</td>
            <td>price2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name3</td>
            <td>price3</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>item1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>G</td>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>R</td>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>T</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table border="1px;" width="100%">
  <tr align="center">
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>quantity</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Totall</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>Item-1</td>
    <td>Item-1</td>
    <td>
      <table border="1px;" width="100%">
        <tr align="center">
          <td>Name1</td>
          <td>Price1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
          <td>Name2</td>
          <td>Price2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
          <td>Name3</td>
          <td>Price3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name4</td>
          <td>Price4</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>Item-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>Item-2</td>
    <td>Item-2</td>
    <td>Item-2</td>
    <td>Item-2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>Item-3</td>
    <td>Item-3</td>
    <td>Item-3</td>
    <td>Item-3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                ...
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by at least adding an explanation and some info. instead of just pasting a block of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TABLE</title>
<style>
    .rb{
        text-align:right;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        border-right:1px solid black;
        border-bottom:1px solid black;
    }
    .b{
        text-align:right;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        border-bottom:1px solid black;
    }
    .r{

        text-align:right;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        border-right:1px solid black;
    }
    .n{
        text-align:right;
    }
    


    
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1px" cellspacing="0px">
<tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Population (In Crores)</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>INDIA</th>
    <td>
    <table cellspacing="0px" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="rb">1998</td>
            <td class="b">85</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="rb">1999</td>
            <td class="b">90</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="r">2000</td>
            <td class="n" >100</td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: run this code you will know where to modify