# How to add nested rows to DOM

Tags: angularjs

```
i got json like this:
{
  rows:[
      {
    nestedrows[
      nested_column0:"hi",
      nested_column1:"man"

    ],
      column0:"whats",
      column1:"up",
      }
  ]
}
```

Now i would like to print all rows with their nested children
im trying to do something like:

http://plnkr.co/edit/y0fWaS0GOBPfaHUygff7?p=preview

But it is impossible because i cant make a tr inside a tr. Any solutions?

Comment: you can add another table in tr element

Comment: You could put a table inside a td: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088868/html-table-tr-inside-td

Comment: ths is not what i want to achieve