# Alternate table row colors for direct child

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to color the rows of my table with differents colors so I'm using this

```
table#news tr:nth-child(even) {      
  background-color: red;
}
table#news tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

It works well with this kind of structure

```
<table id="news">
<tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

But now I work with this kind of table.

```
<table id="news">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <tr><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The style is also applied for the rows inside the rows.

How can I proceed to apply the alternate color only for the first level of `<tr>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
table#news > tr:nth-child(even) {      
  background-color: red;
}
table#news > tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

`>` Means that it's a `#news` has to be a direct parent of the `tr`.

In order for this to work, you also have to add the `tbody` selector.

```
table#news tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {      
  background-color: red;
}
table#news tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

`tbody` element is automatically added by the browser.

Anyway, the above **still won't work** because you can not nest a `tr` inside a `td`. What you have to do is create an entire new table inside the `td`. See this: [Html table tr inside td](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088868/html-table-tr-inside-td)

Run the code snippet below and look at the source code.

```css
table.news > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
table.news > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="news">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="news">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test
      <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 3</td>
      </tr>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h1> Fixed </h1>

<table class="news">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="news">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row 3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```