# Angular 2 Ts possible event on table cell resize

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question aboout angular 2 and ts.
Is iT possible to display content of table cell only when the cell width will be resized ? And hide when back to normal width ?

```
<td class='month-inner'*ngFor="let dates of monthDate; #idx = first" [style.padding-left]="idx === true ? '54px' : ''" >
  <tr style='background-color:#3670af;' >
      <td colspan="3" >{{dates.yearMonth}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>                                                                                                                            
      <th>Ov</th>
      <th>Ov_min</th>
      <th>Pic_Min</th>
  </tr>
```

I want to everything inside "< td class='month-inner' >"shows when width grow. 
I still lerning angular 2 and ts and dont have any ide how to do it

Comment: Yup sometimes you need to do that . A big table with a 6 years data :/

Comment: tr inside a td is not valid, you'd have to [add a new table inside the td](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088868/html-table-tr-inside-td)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is 2 part answer to this.

1. Is there a DOM event that is thrown at the cell width resize?  So
   here is the list of all possible DOM events.
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events There is resize
   event but the resize is on document view resize and not specifically
   for the cell.
2. Given there is a DOM event how to bind it to a function in Angular 2
   so that you can take action?
   This can be achieved as shown here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html As you can
   see in this example they have provided a way to bind an event to
   function

Comment: Hmm a render two other components on is header second is content and its look like this. The content have a button with function onclick. After click  shows cell detaills and table cell extends horizontal. Then in header component column extends too. And i want to apper something inside this header cell after extends.