# html table not working properly when using reactive data in vue 3

Tags: html, vue.js, html-table, vuejs3

[sample table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgKyd.png)

Hi! I wanted to produce a table (see sample table 1for reference). I'm using this code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">test</td>
    <tr>
        <td>test 1</td>
        <td>test 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test 1</td>
        <td>test 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But once I use a reactive data like `<td>{{country}}</td>` to populate the rows, the rows is collapsing.

[collapsed table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnUsj.png)

Can someone please help me with this. By the way I'm using Vue 3

Comment: Please share the whole code when using the reactive data

Comment: You should learn html table syntax first. Mixing `td` and `tr` in same level of nesting is a no-go

Comment: If that is a no-go, can you suggest anything that will be able to produce the result from the first image? thank you

Comment: @majjade-staana Already did

Comment: Structure is wrong. The usage of `tr` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your nesting is incorrect. Don't use `tr` as child of `tr`

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">test</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but it gave me new idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `<tr>` directly in another `<tr>` [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088868/html-table-tr-inside-td)

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">test</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="company in companies" :key="company.id">
    <td :rowspan="company.countries.length+1">{{company.name}}</td>
    <template v-for="country in countries" :key="country.id">
      <tr>
        <td>{{country.contact}}</td>
        <td>{{country.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </tr>
</table>

data(){
 return {
   companies: [
     id: 123
     name: 'test',
     countries: [
       {
        id: 1,
        contact: '0123465',
        name: 'Singapore'
       },
       {
        id: 2,
        contact: '0123465',
        name: 'Myanmar'
       },
     ]
   ]
 }
}
```

This is my first try, that's why i used tr beside td lol. Thank you all, I'll be experimenting how i can achieve my desired output with the correct syntax.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).